# Google Maps Geolocation API only ever returning location of 1st tower in my array

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm trying to make use of the Google Maps Geolocation API. I'm POST-ing a JSON file only containing cell towers to `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MYKEY`.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "cellTowers":[
    {
        "cellId":65535,
        "locationAreaCode":5160,
        "mobileCountryCode":234,
        "mobileNetworkCode":10,
        "signalStrength":-53
    },
    {
        "cellId":34177,
        "locationAreaCode":5160,
        "mobileCountryCode":234,
        "mobileNetworkCode":10,
        "signalStrength":-55
    }
]}
```

This has been validated correct JSON. I'm however having issues getting decent data back from the API.

I've implemented the POST in Java using the Apache HTTPClient & HTTPPost libraries. I get a valid response back, but it's always the LAT,LNG of the first cell tower in the cellTowers array. As if the API is reading the first cell tower, getting the location then ignoring the rest. Of course I've validated that this is the behavior by reversing and shuffling the list and the response changes each time to the first towers location.
Here's my code:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
ConnRouteParams.setDefaultProxy(httpParams, new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT));
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_API);
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

try {
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
    request.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    if(response!=null){
        String jsonResult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        GeolocationResponse geolocationResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonResult, GeolocationResponse.class);

        logger.info(jsonResult);
        logger.info("Est. Location: " + geolocationResponse.toString());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does the Geolocation API only support one cell tower at a time? I thought that it would be more clever than this, using some sort of signal propagation and distance estimation across all the towers.

Comment: Can U post your full code  . . .

Comment: Thanks for looking. I'll dig it out, been a while... Since this post I think I decided that the API is also taking my IP into the calculation, which isn't what I want as I have cell tower data unrelated to my current position.

Comment: This is part of a tapestry app. I've pulled out the relevant bits and put in a normal console app: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6NEPPxoegFQbTJrQ0JWT1lRNWs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a recent communication with Google about our mapping API subscription, I asked for some general info on the Geo-location API. Turns out it doesn't do any complex triangulation of cell tower signals.

Comment: That's a shame. I too expected Google to provide a smarter solution... indeed I came here after seeing only the first of 3 towers was located. Other services like OpenCellID / Unwired Labs takes all towers into account and even the signal strength if you provide it and provides a more accurate location.

Answer (score 1):

They just use the first one considered valid. Reference: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6929